# Ring of integers of a quadratic field when not square-free

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I know what the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ looks like when $d$ is square free, but what is the ring of integers for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for $d=18,45$ etc. Can I just remove the square factors?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. For instance $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{18}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking has nothing to do with rings of integers, but simply with the definition of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$:
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\{a+b\sqrt{d} : a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
Now suppose that $d$ is an arbitrary integer. Then, we can find integers $n\geq 1$ and $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $d=n^2f$, and $f$ is square-free. 
Hence, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{f})$. Let's see this:

- If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, then 
  $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{d}=a+b\sqrt{n^2f}=a+bn\sqrt{f}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{f})$.
- Conversely, if  $\beta=u+v\sqrt{f}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{f})$, then 
  $$\beta=u+\frac{v}{n}\cdot n \sqrt{f}= u+\frac{v}{n} \sqrt{d}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}).$$

Notice that the argument above can be modified slightly to show that, in fact, for every *rational number* $d\in\mathbb{Q}$ there is a square-free integer $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{f})$.

Comment: You don't have to show this in general, it is enough to show that the generators $\sqrt{d}$ and $\sqrt{f}$ lie in the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{f})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I thought that at this level it would be clearer to show the equality of sets completely.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is quite obvious that say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{18}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. This just boils down to the fact that $\sqrt{18} = 3\sqrt{2}$, which is a rational multiple of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It should have been posted as a comment. You should at least explain why it is obvious if you claim it to be so.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in my second sentence...

Comment: Was I wrong to assume that the original poster knows and understands the basics of fields?