# Prove that only units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d] $ are $\pm 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $d(\in \Bbb Z)<-1$ such that $d$ is not divisible  by the square of a prime.
>   Prove that only units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d] $  are $\pm 1$.

$$a+b\sqrt d \text{ is a unit }\implies (a+b\sqrt d)(c+e\sqrt d)=1\implies (a^2-db^2)(c^2-de^2)=1\implies a^2-db^2=\pm 1\implies a+b\sqrt d=\pm1\implies a+b\sqrt d \text{ is a unit}$$

Where did we use that $d$ is not divisible  by the square of a prime.

Is my proof wrong?

Comment: Your proof is correct. The only problem that could happen if $d$ is divisible by the square of a prime is if say $d=-p^2$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] = \mathbb{Z}[i]$  which has more units.

Comment: @SheelStueber; I really did not understand

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135746/ring-of-integers-of-a-quadratic-field-when-not-square-free see this if it helps

Comment: We have a special ring/order, we are not working over $\Bbb Q$. So for instance, i would expect to have $\Bbb Z[\sqrt -9]$ to be the order in $\Bbb Z[i]$ of all elements of the form $a+3ib$, $a,b\in \Bbb Z$. The additional units of $\Bbb Z[i]$, $\pm i$, do not live in this order.

Comment: ah I just assumed it was about integer rings of these quadratic fields is that incorrect @student

Comment: Your proof is right, and the conclusion does not depend on squarefreeness of $d$.

Comment: @Lubin I think the step “$a^2-db^2=\pm1\implies a+b\sqrt{d}=\pm1$” requires a justification.

Comment: I disagree, @egreg, because of the hypothesis that $d<-1$

Comment: @Lubin That's *the* justification!

Comment: Of course, @egreg, as you and I both know, there are infinitely many units when $d>1$. I thought that the setup was rather artificial, though: tailor-made for a quick and dirty route to the desired conclusion, but mathematically much less interesting.

Answer (score 3):

This is why some people prefer to use $-d$ with $d > 0$ rather than $d < 0$. With $-d$, you can then write the norm of a number as $a^2 + db^2$. It then becomes obvious that you can't have $a^2 + db^2 = -1$. Furthermore, as $a$ and $b$ get further away from 0, the norm is correspondingly larger.

So whatever units there are in the ring must have small $a$ and $b$ and therefore be quite close to 0. Thus, for example, in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, we see that $-1$ has a norm of 1 and is therefore a unit, but already $-1 + \sqrt{-5}$ has a norm of 6 and indeed any number in this ring with both $|a|$ and $|b|$ greater than 1 must have a norm greater than 6.

Oh, but we have to mind the so-called "half-integers". For example, $$N\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} = 1.$$ However, $$N\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{7}{4} = 2,$$ so that does it for half-integers that are units.

This is not a rigorous proof, but I do think there is enough here for you to make it one.

Comment: The setup forbids half-integers, of course.

Comment: @Lubin I don't see that Mr. Student at any point explicitly said $d \not \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks He did not. But he has specifief he works in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you meant $d \not \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. If you did mean that, my answer might need slight adjustments.

> $$a + b\sqrt d \text{ is a unit }\implies (a + b\sqrt d)(c + e\sqrt d) = 1$$

So far so good. Of course it should be noted that $\{a, b, c, e\} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. More importantly, however, either $c = -a$ and $e = b$ or $c = a$ and $b = -e$. Without loss of generality (I'm using that correctly, right?), let's rewrite $c + e \sqrt{d}$ as $a - b \sqrt{d}$. Then

> $$(a + b\sqrt d)(a - b \sqrt d) = 1 \implies (a^2 - db^2)(a^2 + db^2) = 1 \implies a^2 - db^2 = \pm 1$$

It is at this point that I would invoke Mr. Soupe's shortcut. Replace $d$ by $-d$ and replace $a^2 - db^2$ with $a^2 + db^2$. Then $d$ is positive and $a^2 + db^2 = -1$ has no solutions. If $d > 1$ (remember the replacement we made just a minute ago), and $b \neq 0$, then $db^2 > 1$ and $a + b \sqrt{d}$ can't be a unit.

So for that number to be a unit, we require $b = 0$. And then if $a > 1$ or $a < -1$ then $a^2 > 1$. I don't have to tell you what happens if $a = 0$. Then, by the process of elimination, $a = \pm 1$, $b = 0$ and therefore the only numbers in the group of units are $\{-1, 1\}$.

Comment: No need to assume anything about $d\pmod 4$. We are working in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$, not in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: @Wojowu Does that come from a question of his I have not seen, or did I miss something in *this* question, Mr. Wowoju?

Comment: The definition of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is the smallest ring containing $\mathbb Z$ and $\sqrt{d}$. This is standard notation.

Comment: Mr. @Wojowu Sounds like the sort of detail I would have been clobbered on from the opposite direction a couple of years ago.

Comment: I understand that feeling completely, Brooks. In any case, it looks like your answer does not really need any adjustments either way.

Answer (score 0):

You're begging the question. You prove that $a^2-db^2=\pm1$, but you can't conclude right now that $a+b\sqrt{d}=\pm1$. What you can derive is that $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit with inverse $\pm(a-b\sqrt{d})$.

Actually, since $d<0$, $a^2-db^2\ge0$, so you can only have $a^2-db^2=1$.

Now $a^2-db^2\ge a^2$. If this is to be equal to $1$, we need $a=0$ or $a=\pm1$. In the first case $-db^2=1$ is impossible, as $d<-1$. So $a=\pm1$ and therefore $b=0$.

There is no need to assume that $d$ is squarefree. This assumption is relevant when you want to consider $\mathbb{Q}[d]$, because this is the same as $\mathbb{Q}[d']$ where $d'$ is squarefree and $d=x^2d'$ for some integer $x$. The field $\mathbb{Q}[d]$ is obviously related to $\mathbb{Z}[d]$, being its field of quotients.

Comment: Why ? $N(a+\sqrt b)=a^2-db^2=1\iff a+b\sqrt d$ is a unit

Comment: @Student Beware of double implications! The $\implies$ direction in your comment is correct; also the reverse implication is true, but requires a proof. But it doesn't help in proving the only units are $\pm1$.

Comment: @Student If you look at the first paragraph in your question, you seem to be proving that “if $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit, then $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit”. However, the penultimate implication has the step “$a+b\sqrt{d}=\pm1$” that's not fully justified.